# Associate JSON ID with list element

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-lists

I have an HTML `<li>` list in which every list element is created using JSON data, using functions in a JS file. I need to be able to delete those records:

`favouritesListMarkup: "<li><a href=\"{{href}}\">{{title}}</a><a href=\"#\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span></a></li>"`

I guess each record in the screenshot below has an index (0, 1, 2 etc) (I tried to create my own called `ID` which is erased in screenshot). How can I associate each list element with the index to delete that specific record?

`[image]

This is the code which adds the favourite:

```
add: function () {
    var item = {};
    item["title"] = this.pageTitle;
    item["url"] = this.currentHref;
    this.fav.push(item);
    this.save();
},
```

Remove function (now this needs the ID in order to be able to delete specific record, and not the record based on the page user is browsing):

```
remove: function () {
    this.findAndRemove(this.fav, "url", this.currentHref);
    this.save();
},

findAndRemove: function (array, property, value) {
    array.forEach(function (result, index) {
        if (result[property] === value) {
            array.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
},
```

Save function just saves it in a local storage, JSON.stringify and sets the item `myFav`. That item can then be accessed to remove records.

Comment: Can you post a snippet please?

Comment: You are not meeting the bare minimum to answer the 'question'. 1) Show your function in which you parse a json string and append the list items to the html-list. 2) You might want to add the structure of your json string to your post as well.

Comment: On what condition you want to delete the record? The last record or the first record or record with title = somename or url= someurl ?

Comment: I want to have a delete button inside an <li> element so that specific record will get deleted. Atm, the delete functions as a button outside of the list which deletes the record when the user is browsing that page. This doesn't work when the page does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ng-repeat to load the list items from JSON, you can use `$index` which will each element index starting from 0